# Why does a scintillator need to be fast decaying?

Tags: photons, electrons, radiation, neutrons, proton-decay

I have two scintillators, say, one with a decay time of 1 ns vs. one with 100 ns. All other parameters like light yield, size of crystal, electronics used, source emission rate, are the same for both. How would their responses differ (say, for neutron irradiation)?

For  purposes like active interrogation, would it really matter which one I use? Which is the limiting factor: timing of scintillator or timing of electronics?

Comment: Tell us what you think and your reasoning. As it stands this sounds like an essay question for a class.

Comment: @BillN I think I didn't frame my question right. So i actually do have two such scintillators, and the 100ns one deinitely collects lesser data in 1 hour than does the plastic (1ns decay),  with the same electronics. But I'm wondering if that really is an issue for most applications. For a high-flux environment may not be so suitable, but for active environments, should not be a problem is my guess. But my quesion is, shouldn't the electronics be limiting rather than the scintillator?

Comment: Perhaps the longer life scintillator is less efficient or has a smaller cross section.

Comment: Are the 2 detectors approximately the same size?  Is one a liquid scintillator and the other solid? A little more info would help.

Comment: you need to consider your count rate.  If the time between detections is long compared to dead time then it (dead time) won't be a factor.

Answer (score 3):

As I stated in my comment you need an estimate of the counting rate. If the time between detections is much larger than dead time, the dead time will not really be a factor.  However, if the time between detections is comparable to the dead time, then a smaller deadtime will increase your detection efficiency.  To determine the time between detections just take a sample count rate and divide it by count time.  So take a sample spectrum for 10 secs say and determine how many detections were counted. Some electronics modules will have a count rate meter built in.

Comment: thank you! i don't really see dead time being an issue. the reason i asked is because im trying to gauge the application versatility of a slow inorganic scintillator.

Comment: your welcome. I'm not familiar with inorganic scintillators but my answer holds regardless. What is the source of the neutrons you detect?  If you are detecting neutrons then your count rate shouldn't be too high. Most neutron will just pass thru/ But like I said if the count rate gets too high you could start missing events.

Comment: i'm using 252Cf.

Comment: @Betsy, I would not assume dead time is negligible.  I advise you to determine the count rate first and then you'll know for sure.  Just for info, is the radioactive source you use on the end of along rod?  If not, how do you handle the 252CF source.  The sources can be pretty strong.